# Calculation of Integral of Pulled-Back $1$-Form.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

I have the function $F: S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1 \times  S^1$ given by $F(p) =(p,p,p)$ and a 1-form $\omega = dt_1 + dt_2 + dt_3$ **over $S^1$**.

I need to do the explicit calculations of 
$\int_{F(S^1 )}\omega$.

I know that $F^{*}\omega = 3\,dt$. But how do i calculate the Integral?

Answer (score 1):

Your first thoughts are correct. To be precise, let's parametrize $S^1\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\theta(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. Let's give $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ coordinates on almost every point by $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ parametrized analogously. Then, your map is $F(\theta)=(\theta,\theta,\theta)$. It follows that the Jacobian for this map is 
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
As a consequence, the Jacobian for the dual map on forms is 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So, as you predicted $F^*(\omega)=F^*(dt_1+dt_2+dt_3)=3 \, d\theta.$ Now, we can use the usual change of variables formula twice to complete the calculation:
$$ \int_{F(S^1)}\omega=\int_{S^1}F^*(\omega) = \int_{S^1} 3 \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}3 \| \theta'(x)\| \, dx=\int_0^{2\pi}3 \, dx=6\pi.$$
Note: You may object to the fact that my parametrization does not cover the whole manifold, but it misses a mere point. The integral is not perturbed by the absence of a measure zero subset of the manifold and so we are done.

Comment: Ok, but i have a theorem that says that if the manifold is closed and the form is exact, the integral is 0. So, what happens here?

Comment: Are you referring to the form $d\theta$? That form is not exact, in spite of the misleading notation. Indeed, you'll notice that it integrates to $2\pi$.

Comment: Im refering to $\omega$

Comment: Well, perhaps you should clarify what your form $\omega$ means and where it is defined.

Comment: Let $\sigma(t_1 , t_2 , t_3 ) = t_1 + t_2 + t_3 $, then $d\sigma = \omega$

Comment: $\omega$ is an 1-form over $S^1$

Comment: Your function $t_1+t_2+t_3$ is not defined over all of $S^1$, since the parametrization $(0,2\pi)\to S^1$ cannot be extended. Addendum: this is basically saying that if you try to define the natural function $\theta$ on $S^1$ it is not globally well-defined.